# finding datetimepicker in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, datetimepicker, toolbox

I cant find "Datetimepicker" in my toolbox of visual studio 2008, can anyone help where to find it and make use of it?
I tried to search it using "choose Items" but I find it there but cant make it visible in toolbox. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not displaying try to add it manually.

Right click on Toolbox --> Add Tab. Once the tab is created--> Right Click--> Use Choose Items--> Here you can select the controls that you want to add. 
[Check this out](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/128314/not-finding-datetimepicker-in-vs-2008.aspx)